# Create A Folder Directory in Excel using Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am extremely new to Visual Basic

I am currently trying to create a calculator within excel that I can export the data within to a PDF. I have been able to export the excel document however it is only going to my "D:\".

How do I create a folder within D:\ called something like Excel_Calculator where I can have all the PDF's created be saved directly into that folder & If there already is a folder called "Excel_Calculator" to use that folder instead of overwriting the existing folder.

The code I have for saving the PDF is listed here:

```
Sub GetFilenameForPDF()
Dim strFileName As String, strB1 As String, strWorksheet As String


strB1 = Range("B1").Value
strWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
strFileName = strB1 & " " & strWorksheet & " " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")




Sub SaveToPDF()

Dim strFileName As String, strC3 As String, strWorksheet As String
strB1 = Range("B1").Value
strWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
strFileName = strB1 & " " & strWorksheet & " " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "D:\" & strFileName & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End Sub
```

** EDIT: Or is there a way I can create or redirect the files to a temporary location so that the folder isn't clogged up and the user can print/save the PDF when needed?**

Comment: `MkDir("D:\afolder")`

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have tried that - haven't been able to make it work. Where would I put that line of code? Because I have tried at the start, end, and in between...

Comment: If you tried that and it failed, describe the error you've got, and show us the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: If I place the code within a new sub the code does not run at all i.e. no new folder is created
And if I place the code outside the subs I receive the compile error. Is there a specific place I should be putting the MkDir line of code?

Sorry still in very early stages of VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using the FileSystemObject

In your VBA project, click Toos->References and add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".

Then, in your code, do something like:

```
Dim fso as FileSystemObject
Dim folderName as String

Set fso = new FileSystemObject
folderName = "D:\MyFolder"
If fso.FolderExists(folderName) = false then
    fso.CreateFolder folderName
End If

Dim strFileName As String, strC3 As String, strWorksheet As String
strB1 = Range("B1").Value
strWorksheet = ActiveSheet.Name
strFileName = folderName + "\" + strB1 & " " & strWorksheet & " " & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"D:\" & strFileName & ".pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply!

I have copied your code and tried it - however now when I press the button to export to PDF I get a VBA error stating "Compile error: invalid outside procedure" and then it proceeds to highlight the word "set" on the 4th line. Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried adding the sub brackets around the code and linking that sub to the export to pdf button

However, this time i got "compile error: method or data member not found" and it highlighted ".exists" and then highlighted sub save () in yellow

[img]https://imgur.com/a/qkLb4[/img]

Comment: the "Invalid outside procedure" error problem comes from your previous sub  GetFilenameForPdf(). Ensure you have End Sub to close that sub i.e. before Sub SaveToPdf(). I don't see it in your original question.

Comment: I have closed off that sub however the same issue regarding the ".exists" error keeps appearing - should I be linking the button to a certain macro? I have tried SaveToPDF() and Save() - both export the document, however don't save in set folder in D:\

Comment: Sorry, please use fso.FolderExists instead of fso.exists

Comment: Okay - so I ran the code and got a myfolder in D:\ , renamed the code to Excel_Calculator and nothing new happened...

How did I break the code?
https://imgur.com/a/hunAr

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to create a single folder or a tree of subfolders. The function uses the (VBA.FileSystem) [MkDir](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mkdir.php) function.

```
Public Function CreateFolderTree(ByVal mainFolder As String, ParamArray args() As Variant) As String
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim path As String
        path = mainFolder & IIf(Right(mainFolder, 1) <> "\", "\", vbNullString)

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        If Len(Dir(path & args(idx), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir path & args(idx)
        path = path & args(idx) & "\"
    Next idx

    CreateFolderTree = path

Leave:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Sub T()
    Dim path_ As String
        path_ = CreateFolderTree("C:\My folder", "Subfolder 1", "Subfolder 2")

    Debug.Print path_

    'C:\My folder\Subfolder 1\Subfolder 2\
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this:

```
Private Declare Function MakeSureDirectoryPathExists Lib "imagehlp.dll" (ByVal lpPath As String) As Long

Public Sub MakeFullDir(strPath As String)
  If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\" 'Optional depending upon intent
  MakeSureDirectoryPathExists strPath
End Sub
```

If the path doesn't already exists, it creates it, even if there are multiple layer of non-existing folders.

E.g: C:\aFolder\bFolder\cFolder\ if only *aFolder* exists this will make *bFolder* and *cFolder*.